# npm has "start" to start which nuget cannot do as a package manager

Tags: javascript, npm, nuget, publish, package-managers

Nuget is a package manager and according to my knowledge it doesn't support a command like `npm start`. Npm is not only a package manager since it support publishing as well. So for nuget is there any option available or can we achieve it in a some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish with nuget, you'll need to download the nuget publish utility from [nuget publish utility](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe) and add it to your system path via controlpanel > system > advanced system settings > environment variables.

Once you've done that, follow the documentation at [creating and publishing a nuget package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package)